# Only ask for a shipping address if a real product is ordered

Tags: commerce

I'm using the Drupal Commerce module with Shipping 7.x-1.0. I created a webshop with both real and virtual products.

My problem is that the shipping address is required even if all the products are virtual (so there is no shipping). How can I make sure that the shipping address is only asked for if the shoppingcart contains real products?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40595/shipping-address-rates-selection-asked-even-if-theres-no-physical-products which is already solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require a custom module:

- Install [Commerce Rules Extra](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra)
- Create a rule for Event: Process checkout pane
- Add Action: Change pane properties

  - Value: Shipping information
  - Page to move to: `<do not change>`
  - Enabled: uncheck
- Add Condition: e.g. by `Order contains products of particular product types`, or based on `Commerce order contains shippable products` supplied by [Commerce Physical Product](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_physical).

You may have to clear caches before this takes effect.

Comment: There is no rule like "Process checkout pane". The rule is named "Process change to a checkout pane".

Answer (score 5):

you could use hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter and do

unset($checkout_pane['customer_profile_shipping']);

only if all line_items contains physical products:

```
function mymodule_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(&$checkout_pane) {
  global $user;

  foreach ($checkout_pane as $pane_name => & $pane_data) {
    if ($pane_name == 'customer_profile_shipping') {
      $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
     if ($order) {
       $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
       $lines = $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items->value();

       $ask_shipping = FALSE;
       foreach ($lines as $line) {
         if ($line->type == 'product') {
           $line_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line);
           $product = $line_wrapper->commerce_product->value();
           if ($product->type == '---> you physical product type <---') {
             $ask_shipping = TRUE;
           }
         }
       }

       if (!$ask_shipping) {
         unset($checkout_pane['customer_profile_shipping']);
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```